# Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator is not letting me create my DLL file or setup package

Tags: windows, keyboard, custom-keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using the decade-old ***Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4*** to create a custom keyboard. I have validated my keyboard within the software and no problems arose. I have also tested my keyboard (multiple times within the software) to make sure the corresponding base and shift keys are functioning properly. However, when I click the button under project to

> "Build DLL and setup Package"

I get the following message:

> "There was a problem building the keyboard file. Would you like to see warning/error information?"

After choosing "yes", I am presented with the following:

```
CL.EXE returned 1

RC.EXE returned 1

LINK.EXE returned 1
```

And an unsuccessful attempt at creating the keyboard layout.

Also, the "There was a problem building the keyboard file" message pops up 4 times. Clicking yes each time brings the same result as the above.

I am a noob in coding and do not know what any of this means, except that all of the 3 programs have returned a "No."

Here is the download link to the software I used:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=22339
(btw, clicking it will automatically download the software)

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem. I was helped by [this Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.international/dR5Z570hwis). The problem is that MSKLC uses some nonstandard filename functionality when it detects spaces in its own filename, which fails and causes some IO issues, which bubble up as three exit codes of 1.

To fix it, you can uninstall MSKLC from the "Add/Remove Programs" section of the Control Panel, and then reinstall it, but instead of installing to Program Files (x86), create a folder directly in C:/ without any spaces (I called mine C:/MSKLC/). After I did that, it worked perfectly for me.